# How to store already-compressed data in ZIP-format?

Tags: python, zip

I have a program, that collects logs from a multitude of machines (over Paramiko), and compresses them into a single ZIP-file. (ZIP-format is used -- despite not being as space-efficient -- because it can be "opened" by unsophisticated users with the plain "Windows Explorer".)

The machines are many and the logs are (sometimes) quite large, so the collecting machine becomes the bottleneck compressing them. Even if I parallelize the compression on the collecting-side, it will *still* be a bottleneck, because the number of servers is (much) larger, than the number of cores I have.

So, naturally, I'd like servers to perform the compression themselves *before sending* -- and then simply archive the data received from them. (Network-transfers will be sped up too.)

How can I tell the `zipfile.writestr()`, that the data given to it is already compressed?

If not `zipfile`, perhaps, some other module can do this?

Comment: use the [`compression=zipfile.ZIP_STORED`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZIP_STORED) keyword argument to denote that the file should just be archived not further compressed. further compression won't hurt anything, but will likely not result in lots of savings, and will take some extra compute (you should do benchmarks both ways to see if it's negligible).

Comment: That will cause the data to not be umcompressed at extraction either... And, yes, compressing the already compressed data is wasteful - this is obvious without benchmarks.

Comment: Double compression may be so fast that you don't need to worry about it, I agree you should benchmark it. And if you add an already compressed file it won't get uncompressed when you extract it whether you double compress it or not.

Comment: @MikhailT. yes, this will result in a zip file full of zip files... Is that so big a problem? It is the simplest solution. Trying to merge pre-compressed files will not be simple.

Comment: "zip file full of zip files" -- the problem is, the log files will not be uncompressed, when the users click on them. The user will get the compressed blob instead of text. Whether it is fast or not is not even relevant.